# Show that the orbit space is homeomorphic to another (simple) space.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $SO(2)$ act on $\mathbb{E}^2$
>   in the usual way.
>
> Which is the
>   resulting orbit space?
>
> Show that the orbit space is homeomorphic
>   to another (simple) space.

---

The group $SO(2)$ consists of all 
$2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices with
determinant $1$, i.e. all matrices which
rotate the plane around the origin.

For $A \in SO(2)$ the action is 
defined by $A(x)=Ax$.

Two points in the
plane is in the same orbit if one
point can be rotated to the other,
i.e. if the two points have the same 
distance to the origin.

Hence the orbit space consists of 
all circles centered at the origin.

---

Can anyone point me in the right direction for the second part of the problem?

Comment: Consider the map $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,\infty),x\mapsto \|x\|$. This induces a homeomorphism on the orbit space. In other words, map every circle to its radius.

Comment: @VincentBoelens Yes, of course. Thank you!